# Bump function has a compact support?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Sorry for the basic question, but couldn't find the answer. We say that the bump function $\phi(x)=e^{-1/(1-x^2)}$ has a compact support. However, $\phi(x)\neq 0$ only for $x \in [0,1)$, which means the support is $[0,1)$. Is $[0,1)$ compact in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Probably the function is defined $$\phi(x) = \begin{cases}\exp \left( - \frac{1}{1-x^2}\right) &, \lvert x\rvert < 1\\ \quad 0 &, \lvert x\rvert \geqslant 1 \end{cases}$$ The support is then $[-1,1]$. Note that the support is the _closure_ of the set where $\phi(x)\neq 0$.

Comment: @Daniel: Ah! Thank you so much. I probably just read over the definition.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, this function, as other [bump functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function), has compact support: namely, $[-1,1]$.

Since the support of a function is closed by definition, and in Euclidean spaces "compact = closed and bounded", one might wonder why we don't say *bounded support* instead. The main reason is that often the domain under consideration is not all $\mathbb R^n$ but  an open subset $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^n$, which could well be bounded itself. The support of a function $u:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is a subset of $\Omega$ which is closed **in $\Omega$** (that is, with respect to the induced topology on $\Omega$). Now the compactness of support hinges on it being at a distance from the boundary of $\Omega$. And this is essential in analysis, where multiplying something by a bump function is a way to avoid dealing with boundary issues.

As an aside, bump functions are sometimes considered on infinite-dimensional vector spaces (typically, Banach spaces). In this case they are understood as (smooth or Lipschitz) functions with *bounded* support. Compactness is rare to find in infinite dimensions.